# Parse track meet output file result

Tags: design-patterns, parsing

I am building out a parser for a well-known track & field meet management software output file ([sample output](http://www.baumspage.com/track/zanetrace/2018/Results%20(meet%20suspended%20after%20girls%203200).htm)).

I can parse this manually, and put items into my object model (overview below), but it's a bit time intensive, and it's going to have manual issues.

FYI, I'm using C# but I have no problem crossing boundaries into better/more appropriate languages here.

I've tried/thought about a couple different ways at this, and they are all just *meh*.

- Use a `StringReader` to parse each line, one-at-a-time, until I run into the "event separators", then try to gather that data together. Parse after.
- Use a `Regex.Split` against a regex that looks something like `Event\s+\d*\s+(Girls|Boys)\s+(.*)\n[=]+\n(.*)\n[=]+` to split the input string into similar chunks. Parse after.
- Use [Amazon Mechanical Turk](https://www.mturk.com/) and hiring a small army of humans to do this work for me.
- Suck it up and keep doing this manually.

So, it's entirely possible that I'm going about this all wrong, and I should be using some language/pattern/concept that I don't even know exists. Any help here would be **greatly** appreciated.

Keep in mind that I don't actually need the code to do the parsing, I am just looking for the idea behind it.

---

The (simplified) object model looks something like this:

- Meet

  - Name
  - Date
  - Location
- School

  - Name
- Athlete

  - Name
  - Gender
  - Graduation Year
- Performance

  - MeetId
  - SchoolId
  - Data (the actual time, height, or distance)
- AthletePerformance

  - AthleteId
  - PerformanceId

Comment: Have you looked into writing the [grammar](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4) for the file format? There are already [a bunch of them](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4).

Comment: I havent @l0b0, but I will absolutely look into it. I knew there was something I was missing.